# How can I select all black pixels that are contiguous with an edge of the image in PIL?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have a set of images petri dishes which unfortunately are not the highest quality (example below, axes aren't part of the images).
[image: dish1]
I'm trying to select the background and calculate its area in pixels with the following:

```
image = Image.open(path)
black_image = 1 * (np.asarray(image.convert('L')) < 12)
black_region = black_image.sum()
```

This yields the below:

[image]

If I am more stringent with my selection of black pixels, I miss pixels in other images, and if I am looser I end up selecting too much of the petri dish itself. Is there a way I can only select the pixels have a luma value less than 12 AND are contiguous with an edge? I'm open to openCV solutions too.

Comment: Are the images all cropped in a fairly similar way - i.e. tops and bottoms of dish missing?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, most of them are very much like this image.

Comment: What do you consider "background"? Anything outside the circle of the the dish? | "not the highest quality" -- keep in mind GIGO principle. Why are they poor quality? What could be done to acquire better ones? No amount of magic will give you back the information you lost due to poor image acquisition.

Comment: It's apparent from your other questions that the axes are not part of the original image.

Comment: @joeforker The axes are not part of the image. it's just from calling `plt.imshow()` I'll edit above and clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully, I'm not oversimplifying the problem, but from my point of view, using OpenCV with simple thresholding, morphological operations, and [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) should do the job.

Please, see the following code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Input
input = cv2.imread('images/x0ziO.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Input to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(input, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Binary threshold
_, gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Morphological improvements of the mask
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5)))
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11)))

# Find contours
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Filter large size contours; at the end, there should only be one left
largeCnts = []
for cnt in cnts:
    if (cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 10000):
        largeCnts.append(cnt)

# Draw (filled) contour(s)
gray = np.uint8(np.zeros(gray.shape))
gray = cv2.drawContours(gray, largeCnts, -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Calculate background pixel area
bgArea = input.shape[0] * input.shape[1] - cv2.countNonZero(gray)

# Put result on input image
input = cv2.putText(input, 'Background area: ' + str(bgArea), (20, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1.0, (255, 255, 255))

cv2.imwrite('images/output.png', input)
```

The intermediate "mask" image looks like this:

[image: Mask]

And, the final output looks like this:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

> Since you are open to OpenCV approaches you could use a
>   `SimpleBlobDetector`

Obviously the result I got is also not perfect, since there are a lot of hyperparameters to set. The hyperparameters make it pretty flexible, so it is a decent place to start from.

This is what the Detector does (see details [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/)):

1. **Thresholding**: Convert the source images to several binary images by thresholding the source image with thresholds starting at minThreshold. These thresholds are incremented  by `thresholdStep` until `maxThreshold`. So the first threshold is `minThreshold`, the second is `minThreshold + thresholdStep`, the third is `minThreshold + 2 x thresholdStep`, and so on.
2. **Grouping**: In each binary image,  connected white pixels are grouped together.  Let’s call these binary blobs.
3. **Merging**: The centers of the binary blobs in the binary images are computed, and  blobs located closer than `minDistBetweenBlobs` are merged.
4. **Center & Radius Calculation**:  The centers and radii of the new merged blobs are computed and returned.

*Find the code bellow the image.*

[image: Output Image]

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("petri.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 0
params.maxThreshold = 255

# Set edge gradient
params.thresholdStep = 5

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 10

# Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                                      cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you take the very top line/row of your image and the very bottom line/row and threshold them you will get this diagram where I have placed the top row at the top and the bottom row at the bottom just outside the limits of the original image - there is no need for you to do that, I am just illustrating the technique.

[image]

Now look where the lines change from black to white and then white to black (circled in red at the top). Unfortunately, your images have annotations and axes which I had to trim off so your number will not be identically the same. On the top line/row, my image changes from black to white at column 319 and back to black at column 648. If I add those together I get 966 and divide by 2, the image centre on the x-axis is at column 483.

Looking at the bottom line/row the transitions (circled in red) are at columns 234 and 736 which add up to 970 which makes 485 when averaged, so we know the circle centre is on vertical image column 483-485 or say 484.

Then you should now be able to work out the image centre and radius and mask the image to accurately calculate the background.

Answer (score 2):

Try the experimental `floodfill()` method. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html?highlight=floodfill#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill

If all your images are like the example, just pick two or four corners of your image to fill with, say, hot pink and count that.

See also [Image Segmentation with Watershed Algorithm](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) which is much like flood fill but without relying on a single unique color.

Comment: I tried using floodfill, but I'm not sure if I'm using it properly. I keep getting an image that is entirely filled with the fillcolor I specify with `ImageDraw.floodfill(image, (100,100), (32, 200, 32), 0 )`. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Try thresh of 50 and alpha channel 255 on the color