# python cv2 remove black noise inside the white color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lo9Q.jpg)
[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEBtL.png)

I tried many ways but it didn't remove the black dot inside the white. How do I get it off white?

Comment: [edit] your question and list all the ways you've tried, and what the results were. please review [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not sure what you've tried already, I would recommend looking into contiguous thresholding or open contours as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55605352/4175601).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.